# What does rake assets:precompile do without RAILS_ENV=production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I run the following commands and then visit a page it gives an error about routing failure on an asset.

```
rake assets:precompile
rails s -e production
```

However if I do the same after the following commands where I've added RAILS_ENV=production everything works.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
rails s -e production
```

What is `rake assets:precompile` doing when I omit `RAILS_ENV=production` that explains why it is not working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is precompiling the assets in your default environment, which is more than likely `developement`